# angular resolve reload when same route reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I reload the Angular resolve with the reload?

#### My code :

```
.when('/dashbord', {
    title: 'dashbord',
    templateUrl: 'views/dashbord.php',
    controller: 'dashbordController',
    resolve: {
        getDashbord: function (getDashbordService) {
            return getDashbordService;
        }
    }
})
```

#### Reload function :

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$templateCache', function ($rootScope, $route, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.changeRoute = function(){
        var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
        $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
        $route.reload();
    };
}]);
```

The above function reload only the view. It doesn't reload the resolve.

How can i do it in angular ?

Answer (score 1):

I created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aNXP0ET1X5hGKTa1ed8B?p=preview) for you that shows that

```
$route.reload()
```

**fires resolve on state**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but one thing to keep in mind is that Angular services are singletons -- which means if you define your resolve function as a service (esp. one that makes an `$http` request), you will get the same results each time the route resolves.

For example, this uses an Angular service that makes an `$http` request, and won't make a new `$http` request on `$route.reload()`:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('getDashboardService', ['$http', function getDashboardService($http) {
    return $http.get('/path/to/resource'); // returns a promise
}]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        title: 'dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.php',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        resolve: {
            getDashbord: 'getDashboardService' // refers to an Angular service
        }
    });
}]);
```

...but this will, because it is not an injected service:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        title: 'dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.php',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        resolve: {
            getDashboard: ['$http', function($http) {
                return $http.get('/path/to/resource');
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/77ys9hz5/